# Extjs 5.1 Ext.getStore('example').load() error 404 not found model

Tags: extjs, store, extjs5

I have a problem with the store, it shows the console "404 model not found" this happens when clicking on the combobox which has the store defined, when I do a .setstore to the combobox also when using Ext.getStore('test') .load(). the information loads correctly and does not affect the flow of the system, but shows the error on the console.
How do I avoid the 404 error of the model?

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxdvJ.png)
[store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWjlF.png)
[combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0rzf.png)
[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfGJN.png)
[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAphI.png)

The store was changed to memory and the error is not displayed in the console but the data is not loaded in the combobox either
[proxy memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBQc9.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [don't post your code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: I think "404 model not found" is a server side error. It is not a client side error.